# Yii2 Контроллер отправляет NULL в БД

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

Имеется в таблице 2 строк: это id(autoincrement) и title

Контроллер отправляет NULL почему ?

Вот мой Модель

```
namespace common\models;
use Yii;

class Regi extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public $id;
public $title;
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'regi';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title'], 'required',  'message'=>'require'],
        [['title'], 'string'],
        [['title'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'id',
        'title' => 'title',
    ];
}
}
```

Вот контроллер

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\main\controllers;

use common\models\Regi;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use frontend\components\Common;
use Yii;

use yii\filters\AccessControl;


class RegiController extends Controller
{
public $layout = "bootstrap";

public function actionIndex()
{

    $model = new Regi();   
    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
        } else {
            $errors = $model->errors;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
}
}
```

Вот views

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<ol>

                <li><label class="labels"><?php echo \Yii::t('content', 'title'); ?>: </label><?php echo $form->field($model,'title')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?></li>


</ol>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-11">
                        <?php echo Html::submitButton('register', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                    </div>

                </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

var_dump($model) показывает что передает данные в контроллер

Comment: var_dump($model->getAttributes()) после load() что отображает?

Comment: array(2) { ["id"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(4) "1234" }

Comment: `public $id;
public $title;` уберите это

Comment: Blacknife спасибо.Все прошло успешно.